# Why do I only get one bezier handle on a point in graph editor?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, graph-editor

I am animating the Factor of a Cast modifier and and would like to smooth out the animation by using bezier handles. But I only get one handle on the right side of the point. Where is the left one? I've marked the point in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: The left handle is probably very close to the curve point or too small on the current graph. Select the point you want to modify and press numpad period (.) to zoom in. Or press V to change the frame handle

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that to no avail, but I figured out that if I change the point to the left (frame 1 in screenshot) to a bezier, the left handle appears. So I guess the previous point have to be a bezier for the left handle to work. Don't understand why though.